# Can not find WSO2(wsf.dll) file for Xampp

Tags: php, wso2, wsh

i want to install WSO2 for XAMPP 
I find this tutorial: http://wso2.com/library/3076/#link1
I download wso2 from : https://github.com/wso2/wsf 
but as shown in tutorial i can not find wsf.dll file in my downloaded file ( php folder )
so the content is a bit different.
and i can not find wso2-wsf-php-bin-1.2.0-win32 to download

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can download only the source code files from https://github.com/wso2/wsf and you need to compile it, after you compiled, you will see the wsf.dll in the compile directory.

If you use linux, read README.INSTALL file
if you use windows, read README.INSTALL_WIN32